# jQuery in IE8 .css() returning undefined for value

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This seems to fail in IE8 (haven't tested 7, but surely it will fail too) The `value` in the function returns `undefined`. It works fine in Firefox:

```
$('selector').css('property', function(index, value){ alert(value); });
```

The actual code from my script is as follows:

```
$('.scrollBkg').css('background-position', function(index, value){
    var backgroundPosition = value.split(' ');
    return (parseFloat(backgroundPosition[0]) + (($(this).hasClass('scrollLeft') ? -1 : 1) * parseInt($(this).css('z-index'))) / 2) + 'px ' + backgroundPosition[1];
});
```

Why is it that `value` is `undefined` in IE? Rather, how can I make this work as expected?

Comment: Note: Unless someone can tell me otherwise, IE floors the value if provided a float for `background-position`. Therefore, incrementing `background-position` by `0.5px 0px` will not move the background image 0.5 pixels to the right, it will do nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MSIE retrieve **backgroundPositionY** and **backgroundPositionX** instead of **backgroundPosition**

```
var backgroundPosition = (document.all && !window.opera)
                              ?[$(this).css('backgroundPositionX'),
                                $(this).css('backgroundPositionY')]
                              : value.split(' ');
```

Comment: Also; Although its working, it appears to be acting strangely. Would it be advantageous for me to set the new background position value via the `backgroundPositionX`/`Y` properties for IE?

Comment: This could be an opptortunity. The strange behaviour with backgroundPosition is not documented on MSDN, by this I can't tell you what IE is doing wrong there.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. It appears to be as I mentioned in the comment on my question. I suppose IE doesn't support non-integer values for `background-position`, flooring values like `0.5` to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is your problem, but ... IE7 as well as 8 has issues with singel quotes for selector/id values, and might not find the respective DOM element.

Recently I just finished a jquery project very high on IE side and I switched all my ' quotes to " to make it work.

in your case try:

```
$("selector").css("property", function(index, value){ alert(value); });
```

So what I am suggesting is that IE never found your element and thus cannot append a new class to it, therefore "undefined"

For any css value in jquery I tend to use double quotes ... instead of single quotes.

Comment: selector values are just javascript strings - there should be no problem with using single quotes vs double quotes.  You may be thinking about html attributes, where single quotes are not valid html (`<div id='foo'>` - is invalid html).  Also, in this context, if IE never matched the selector, then the resulting set would be empty, and the function would never be called at all.

Comment: Thanks **mahatmanich**; I've not yet had any problems using single quotes anywhere at anytime. Odd that you've had such luck though. I often use single quotes in order to use double quotes for attribute selectors in jQuery selector strings. Eg: `$('[foo="bar"]')`

Comment: I also thought there would be no issue, but the code would just not work for me in IE7 with single quotes ... but thanks for the heads up, the issue must have been some place else. I will revisit my code and see if it works with '' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

according to the [relevant section of the jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> > `function(index, value)`: A function returning the value to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

So if there were no value previously set, I would expect that `value` might be `undefined`, or maybe `null`.  I could see this behavior being different between browsers -- essentially, it's a question of what the browser's default value is for the css property you're working with.  IE's default might be `undefined`, while firefox defaults to a more meaningful value.

Comment: Thanks **Lee**; It appears that Dr. Molle is right, however, in my reading it was mentioned in a tutorial for something similar to default the value to something like `0px 0px`

Comment: @TomcatExodus: thanks for the follow up. I'm glad you got it sorted out.